# stocktwits api how do i fetch all tweets from a given ticker using python

Tags: python, api, stocktwits

Novice first time using a web API. I'm trying to get data off of stocktwits API using a python script. The examples in their doc is kind of dry and assumes familiarity with using web APIs. Any more fleshed out examples out there or tips/links?

Specific Question: how to get all tweets from a given ticker in a given historical time frame?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey thank you for that. I've attempted to improve it a little.

Comment: Looks like [this is the method](http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#streams-symbol-docs) you want for accessing the messages regarding any given ticker.. but you might need to [get special permission to access historical data for a given ticker](http://stocktwits.com/developers/contact) as it seems like the method only returns the 30 most recent messages.

Comment: It seems you are correct.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a module I wrote and have been using a while to use Python with StockTwits.  Hope it helps!
https://github.com/hamx0r/stocktwits